# android spinner value doesn`t stop player

Tags: java, android

Anybody knows why this code doesn't stop my player from playing?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

     if(pos == 1) {  

                    if (aacPlayer != null) {
                        aacPlayer.stop();
                        aacPlayer = null;
                    }



     }

        }
```

I run the app and when i select the certain value of the spinner that is supposed to stop aacplayer, i get this:

```
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at com.spoledge.aacplay.AACPlayerActivity.onItemSelected(AACPlayerActivity.java:380)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-29 12:14:59.279: E/AACPlayer(1608):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use try catch & print the value of pos...

Comment: `AACPlayerActivity.java` see line no .380

Answer (score 0):

well,  i guess "pos" variable is never 1?

Try remove it.

Comment: well if i put a text in it works, but if i want to command aacplayer to stop it doesnt

Comment: your accPlayer is probably null then. can you check if its null?